# Byte Order Mark preventing Django app deployment to Heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I've been trying to learn Django, and I've been running into some trouble deploying to Heroku. When I try running `git push heroku master`, I get the following output

```
PS E:\My\Git\Directory> git push heroku master
Counting objects: 31, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (26/26), done.
Writing objects: 100% (31/31), 6.71 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 31 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.2 (you are using 
ÿþpython-3.6.2, which is unsupported).
remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version 
(python-3.6.2).
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-
runtimes
remote: -----> Installing ÿþpython-3.6.2
remote:  !     Requested runtime (ÿþpython-3.6.2) is not available for this 
stack (heroku-16).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to intense-river-64521.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/intense-river-64521.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/intense-river-
64521.git'
```

Running the site on localhost has no problems. My `runtime.txt` only contains:

```
python-3.6.2
```

I assumed the issue was that `ÿþ` is a hidden character in `runtime.txt`, so I tried encoding it in UTF-8 and ANSI and neither worked. Visual Studio Code also showed no hidden characters in the file. Is there another location where the python runtime can be specified?

Comment: It says "ÿþpython-3.6.2" which is not the same version that written in your `runtime.txt`

Comment: Oops sorry, I was testing something else when I posted this, but `runtime.txt` actually contains `python-3.6.2`

Comment: Can you delete your runtime.txt, then from a shell simply type `echo python-3.6.2 >> runtime.txt`? That might do it. Either way, 3.6.2 is the default anyway, so you could just delete your `runtime.txt` for a quickfix.

Comment: Just tried both solutions and got the same error both times. If there is no `runtime.txt` does Heroku automatically determine the python runtime to be the latest version?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#selecting-a-runtime it's written right there on the website